# What benefits are there of using an ARM device like Raspberry Pi?

Tags: full-node, nodes, raspberry-pi

I've seen ARM listed as one of the options on the Monero website. What benefits are there of using Monero with an ARM device like Raspberry Pi instead of a traditional computer?

Are there any energy or security benefits of running using a Raspberry Pi to run a full node or creating offline wallets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is good for testing the minimum resource requirements needed to run Monero. As long as Monero continues to work on ARM devices like the Raspberry Pi then scaling concerns related to hardware requirements will not be a problem for most people.

It also is extremely inexpensive in terms energy consumption, with a Raspberry Pi and other ARM systems able to operate as a full node with only 1 or 2 watts of electricity.

Security benefits of using a Raspberry Pi result from it being isolated from other irrelevant (to Monero) programs installed on every modern PC. Such an isolation model is ideal for creating offline wallets for cold storage.

Comment: Speaking of energy consumption, a typical Pi and other ARM systems of that type can operate as a full node on only 1-2W of electricity. Mining would drive up the cost, but at the moment mining speeds on ARM are too slow to bother.

Comment: Good point about the isolation bit. RPi's make a decent air-gapped computer, and are also great for generating offline wallets.

Comment: "and offers the security benefit of being isolated from other irrelevant (to Monero) programs installed on every modern PC." This is especially true if you use Arch Linux, since only what is necessary to run linux is installed by default. I'm not sure if you can run Monero on Arch Linux though.

Comment: There's a guide for running Monero on Arch Linux [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/502o8v/i_didnt_see_a_monero_setup_guide_for_arch_linux).